# Prevent users from typing letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my program I have asked the user some basic maths questions. But I don't want them to be able to type a letter. Is there a function or method out there that would allow me to create an error message and ask them to re-enter the answer.

```
Answer = int(input ("What is the answer to the question?"))

if Answer == Maths:
        print ("Correct.")
        Score += 1

#function/method to prevent them from entering letters:
        print ("Please enter a valid answer.")

if Answer != Maths:
        print ("Incorrect.")
```

Edit - I basically don't want them to enter a letter but in a way it doesn't crash.

Comment: You need some kind of console or curses module for this, there isn't a simple solution. Since you're just starting to program you should just be validating the input instead.

Comment: You should take a look at regular expressions as well. They would allow you to do some simple text input validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to wait for a valid integer:

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter an integer value.')
    return answer

# Ask for 10 integers
for i in range(3):
    print(get_int('Enter an integer: '))
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer: 1
1
Enter an integer: 2
2
Enter an integer: a
Please enter an integer value.
Enter an integer: b
Please enter an integer value.
Enter an integer: 3
3
```

If `answer` can't be converted to an integer, it will throw a `ValueError` exception and continue in the `while` loop.  If `answer` is valid it will break from the loop.

Comment: The whole program is already in a for loop. Would that still work?

Comment: @Joe, probably not.  You'll want it to wait in the `while` until a valid integer is entered.  I edited my answer to show a reusable function to prompt for integers.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way of doing this:

```
import string
user_input = ' '

while not all(char in string.digits for char in user_input):
    user_input = raw_input("Enter only numbers")
user_input = int(user_input)
```

`string.digits` is the string `0123456789`.